# ReactJS router V4.0, navigation of pages works with browser arrows and Manually typing pages. But when clicking on Link, its not getting rendered

Tags: reactjs, router

Its a very simple sample, where navigation of pages works with browser arrows and Manually accessing Pages. But when clicking on Link, component is not getting rendered. What could be the issue, how to identify!!!

Here is the code:

index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First application</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="App">
    <div class="container" id="AppContainer"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="../node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './Scripts/AppContainer.jsx';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
      <HashRouter>
      <App/>
      </HashRouter>
      ), document.getElementById('AppContainer')
);
```

AppContainer.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,  browserHistory, Route,  Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header.jsx';
import Main from './Main.jsx';

class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
             <div>
                 <Header/>
                 <Main/>
             </div>  
      );
    }
}


export default App
```

Header.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

import { BrowserRouter as Router,  Route,  Switch, Link, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from  './Home.jsx';
import About from  './About.jsx';

class Header extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
                <header>
                   <Router>
                       <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to='/About'>About</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                        </nav>
                   </Router>
                </header>  
         );
    }
}


export default Header
```

Main.JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, browserHistory,  Route,  Link ,  hashHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from  './Home.jsx';
import About from  './About.jsx';

class Main extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <main>
              <Router  >
                <div>

                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/About" component={About}/>

               </div>
              </Router>
              </main>
      );
    }
}

export default Main
```

About.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';


class About extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return <div> <h2>About</h2> </div>
    }
}

export default About
```

Home.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

Comment: Try using <Route exact path="/About" component={About}/>

Comment: Hi Sridhar, I tried with exact not working still

Comment: Just a hunch, but it might have something to do with the fact that you have more than one `<Router />` component

Comment: Yes that's right, have made it work...